# std::chrono 's inaccuracy when using it in a quick loop

Tags: c++, performance-testing, c++-chrono

I'm trying to measure some functions' run time (i.e. Quicksort and Mergesort). I want to run several tests so I'm using a "for" loop to execute the function and measure it's run time several times. The problem is, I will get some random, inaccurate run time measurements in some of the test cases.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

auto seed = static_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
std::mt19937_64 rand_num(seed.count());

template <typename T, typename U>
void swap(T *a, U i, U j) {
    T temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

template <typename T>
void quicksort(T *a, unsigned long long left, unsigned long long right) {
    unsigned long long i = left , j = right;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> range(0, (right - left) / 2);
    T pivot = a[left + range(rand_num)];

    while (left < j or i < right)
    {

        while (a[i] < pivot)
        i++;
        while (a[j] > pivot)
        j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            swap(a, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }

        else
        {
            if (left < j)
            quicksort(a, left, j);
            if (i < right)
            quicksort(a, i, right);

            return;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long size, test, i;
    long long x, y;

    std::cout << "Test cases: ";
    std::cin >> test;
    std::cout << "Array size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<long long> a(size);
    std::cout << "\nEnter the Minimum Size for the numbers: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "\nEnter the Maximum Size for the numbers: ";
    std::cin >> y;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> range(x, y);

    for (unsigned long long b = 1; b <= test; b++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= size-1; i++)
            a[i] = range(rand_num);

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        quicksort(a.data(), 0, size-1);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::nanoseconds(end - start).count();
        std::cout << "\nTest " << b << ": " << elapsed << " Nanoseconds";
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. This works fine with online IDEs (I used http://cpp.sh/)
2. My compiler is g++ 5.3.0-1 following c++14 language standards
3. My IDE is code::blocks

Comment: I think you can't measure _nanoseconds_ with lots of accuracy.

Comment: @ForceBru
But how did it work perfectly with an online IDE?

Comment: the operating systems are different and the hardware is different as well. Counting such small fractions of seconds isn't that easy, to my mind, and different systems do it with different accuracy.

Comment: @ForceBru
So.... The system will just return 0 when it didn's measure the time?

Comment: @AmiraliMohammadi: No, the system returns the current time. **You** calculate `end-start` which indeed can be 0 if the clock didn't change in the mean time.